# Differentiate between admin login and user login in php

Tags: php, authentication

I am new to php, I am trying to create a login page form as

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Login: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login as admin user">
<input type="submit" value="Logins as Student">
```

I want to differentiate,which submit button user clicked and direct to him to corresponding page

i.e if he click Login as user he should forward to adminLogin.php or Vise Versa.

Comment: If you're  going to do it in this style, I would suggest a radio button with the name `userType`. Set one value to `admin` and the other to `student`, then check  (in your PHP portion) for the `$_POST['userType']` to see if it's admin or student.

Comment: Why not just have the same login functionality then modify the user object/session accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

just add status Column into the database like a Status=1 and Status=0 if Status 1 found then admin and Status 0 are found then user.

Answer (score 0):

Better things is to add a column in your database to distinguish the user type and fetch the data while login according to the credentials entered and redirect accordingly.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer, no?

Comment: Why not make two different tables `admin` and `students`? That way he can connect any other data that only pertains to students or admin to the appropriate user type.

Comment: @steve Most of the time, the login functionality need only username and password, then what is the purpose of using two tables since the more detailed information are storing in separate tables which is the best practice which I know to my best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of register make differentiation between admin login and user login. Then when log in process will take place, you can easily identfy whether user logging in or admin logging in. Redirect them then to other page.

Answer (score 0):

First, assign unique id to each button:

```
<input type="submit" id="adminLogin" value="Login as admin user">
<input type="submit" id="userLogin" value="Logins as Student">
```

Now, you can do this via jquery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#adminLogin").click(function(){
          $('form').attr("action", "adminLogin.php");
     });
     $("#userLogin").click(function(){
          $('form').attr("action", "userLogin.php");
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one column in your database table, with specify the role of user is it admin or user, Then depending on its value, you your related login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a table `users` with schema like,

```
user_id |  name    | password  | type
1          admin     admin        1
2          memeber   member       0
```

For instance, you can have 1 as admin and 0 as member.

So, in form you can have a code,

```
<form action="validate.php" method="post">
Login: <input type="text" name="name">
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
</form>
```

In `validate.php`, check whether he's a admin or student by,

```
  <?php

  $db = mysqli_connect("specify host here","specify db username","specify db password","specify db name");

   if(isset($_POST['login']) // check whether user submits the form
   {

        $name_b = $_POST['name'];
        $password_b = $_POST['password'];

        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$name_b); // escaping special characters
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$password_b);

        $query = "SELECT `type` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '$name' AND `password` = `$password` LIMIT 1 ";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query)

        if($result)
        {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $user_type = $row['type']; // you get user type here whether he's admin or login

        if ($user_type == 1) { 

             // this use is admin
            // do stuff here or redirect to admin panel or wherever you want
        }

        elseif ($user_type == 0) {
            // this user is member
            // do stuff here or redirect wherever you want
        }

        else
        {
            // if there's some other value, simplyredirect to login page again
        }
      } // close of if($result)
     else
     {
        echo "query failed"; // redirect to login page again
      }

    }

    else
    {
        // redirect to login page again         
    }




 ?>
```